# Batch file to create a text file with the same name as every .zip file in a directory

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm not very familiar with windows batch scripts except very simple applications. I'm currently trying to figure out how to run a batch file in a local directory, scan the directory for each *.zip file and then create a corresponding .txt file (in the same local directory). This will run indefinitely at intervals of say... 5 seconds. Any clues to help? Would it be easier to write a Java program or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it:

```
@echo off
:loop
FOR %%G IN (*.zip) DO TYPE nul>"%%~nG.txt"
timeout /t 300
goto loop
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the FOR command to iterate through files in a directory.  The TYPE command creates an empty file.

```
@echo off
FOR %%G IN (*.zip) DO TYPE nul>"%%~nG.txt"
```

Comment: Just how do i get it to loop every X amount of time?